# Altering stored procedure from another procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I would like to know how to alter a stored procedure from another stored procedure. I have created one stored procedure called `dbo.change`, and in this procedure I would like to alter other stored procedure that needs to be altered.

But currently I use `alter procedure` and when the change procedure is compiling it fails at the alter. Is there a method of doing this?

Comment: why would you need to that?

Comment: I do not know why you would want to do that, but you could use a dynamic sql.

Comment: It might be possible using dynamic sql, but why would you want to do this? What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: because i need to make changes to a live database, and am testing it on a local one to see changes to the tables don't affect the data, and these procedure have local data-type declared need to change these so they match the new table schema

Comment: @user3086751 the real question is the one behind your 'because i need to make changes to a live database'. which changes you need to make? why they do have to be performed by a stored procedure? imho the solution you are trying to implement is a paved highway to major troubles: executing alter statements from stored procedures will produce naive behaviour almost impossible to trace & debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL to alter a stored procedure from within another.  For example:

```
ALTER PROC dbo.Change
AS
EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER PROC dbo.SomeOtherProc AS ...';
GO
```